# SQL: group by, order by and concat the results

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

Is there a functionality in sql which can perform this efficiently?

Figuratively, I have a database with three columns: `tape_date`, `empl`, and a single character column `val`; I want to extract the most recent 3 values of `val` for each `empl` concatenated together in the order of their `tape_date`.  For example for the table below I should get a row

```
bob, DEA
```

and similarly for other `empl`'s. The order matters, so for example `EDA` would be wrong result for `bob`.

I am using Sybase `Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7.0`, but prefer not to use proprietary features.

```
tape_date    empl    val
------------------------
2014-01-08   bob     A
2014-01-01   bob     G
2014-01-03   alice   K
2014-01-02   bob     D
2014-01-05   bob     E
```

Comment: What version of SYBASE?

Comment: This is not a thing you can do easily without using proprietary functions.

Comment: @FilipeSilva, depending on what he is doing with the information, I disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this, one is to use the Sybase LIST function if you don't mind it only running on Sybase. If not then you can do it using RANK and MAX. Like so:

```
SELECT 
  CAST('2014-01-03' AS DATE) AS tape_date
  ,'alice' AS empl   
  ,'K' AS val
INTO #temp_table;
INSERT INTO #temp_table VALUES('2014-01-08', 'bob', 'A');
INSERT INTO #temp_table VALUES('2014-01-01', 'bob', 'G');
INSERT INTO #temp_table VALUES('2014-01-02', 'bob', 'D');
INSERT INTO #temp_table VALUES('2014-01-05', 'bob', 'E');


-- USING SYBASE ONLY LIST FUNCTION
SELECT empl, SUBSTR(LIST(val ORDER BY tape_date), 1, 5)
FROM #temp_table
GROUP BY empl;

-- THE GENERIC WAY
SELECT 
  empl
  ,MAX(CASE rank WHEN 1 THEN val ELSE '' END) 
    + ',' 
    + MAX(CASE rank WHEN 2 THEN val ELSE '' END)
    + ',' 
    + MAX(CASE rank WHEN 2 THEN val ELSE '' END)
FROM (
SELECT
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY empl ORDER BY tape_date) AS rank
  ,*  
FROM #temp_table) a
WHERE rank <= 3
GROUP BY 
  empl
```

Comment: `RANK()` is not generic.  It was not in MS SQL Server until version 2005.

Comment: @D Stanley - true, when I said generic I was referring to not using proprietary features as per the question. The question didn't specify that it had to be backwards comparable as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to "flatten" the rows returned by the group by query is by using a procedural language (T-SQL, C#, Java). Not possible in SQL alone.

Comment: I have never used sybase, but I am pretty sure it uses T-SQL

Comment: Sybase has the LIST function which will flatten a column, the default is comma separated but you specify any combination of characters. you can also tell what order you want ant make it a distinct list.